# Can I restore an uncompressed differential backup after a compressed full backup?

Tags: sql-server, restore, compression

If we enable compression on database backups (because the database backup size is huge) but don't enable it on differential which are relatively small in size, will a restore work? Because the full backup is compressed but the differential isn't compressed.

Comment: While this will work, I would suggest always using compression. What do you gain by NOT doing it some of the time, even if "some of the time" is just on small file sizes?

Answer (score 7):

This is really a question for the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) but yes, it will work. Compression is transparent when restoring, and the [`RESTORE` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) doesn't need any parameter to tell it that a backup is compressed.

Of course you can easily test this yourself.

Comment: ... just make sure that the Full is restored `WITH NORECOVERY`

Answer (score 2):

Yes the restore will work just fine. Every edition of SQL Server 2008 and later can restore a compressed backup.

Refer : [Backup Compression (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx) for more details.